# Avoid areas that are too dense with the same points

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have this plot, as you can see there are red and blue points.
[image]

The points have been randomly plotted, basically, my task is that i need to identify red and blue areas where there is more concentration of the **same** color.

With "concentration" i mean an area (or more than one area) where blue or red are >80% more than the other color.

The problem is that i cannot use a clustering algorithm because i already know the classes, I only need to find a mechanism that discard areas where there are the same cencentration of both colors (50% each less or more).

The rules i would use are:

1. an area where there are more than X points
2. the points of that area are 80% (at least) of the same color.

So my goal is passing a "test point" and understand if it is in a specific area or not.

***Is there an algorithm to do something like that?***

***NOTE:*** The areas on the plot are (obviously) manually painted, just to give you a sense of what i need to do, programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such algorithm, in part because you have too many free parameters to the problem statement.  From the regions you drew, it seems that you also have some expectation that the region will be

- cohesive -- you didn't send out tendrils to include readily available nearby points
- convex -- again, you didn't send out tendrils that thread their way around points of the opposite color
- discriminating -- in some cases, you included an enemy point; in others, you didn't bother, even though you would have picked up more friendly points and maintained your 80% majority.

This is a problem first in defining your area membership; then, it's a problem in heuristics and image processing.  Those heuristics will depend very much on your area membership standards.